# setting a default enabled radiobutton in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I used [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/RadioButtonTableExample.htm) guide in order to make `JTable` that would handle radio buttons. Works fine except i need to enable a default enabled button.

there can be n rows. I've tried to enable it through the default table model, the `Object[][]`, the table, and i tried enabling the button before adding it to the `Object[][]`. I couldn't figure out how(if it is possible) to do it with the buttongroup.

to find the default enabled button i have to compare the button text to a string(this part works).

Comment: never-ever store components in a tableModel, that's completely wrong ... Instead, store _data_ that can be rendered by a custom rendering component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure that I am interpreting the question correctly. You can use `JRadioButton` constructor to set selection, for example the snippet (based on OP code sample) will set selected button "B":

```
dm.setDataVector(new Object[][] { { "Group 1", new JRadioButton("A") },
    { "Group 1", new JRadioButton("B", true) },
    { "Group 1", new JRadioButton("C") },
    { "Group 2", new JRadioButton("a") },
    { "Group 2", new JRadioButton("b") } }, new Object[] {
    "String", "JRadioButton" });
```

You can also change selection like this:

```
((JRadioButton) dm.getValueAt(0, 1)).setSelected(true);
```

You can also use `ButtonGroup.setSelected()` method.

***EDIT: eliminate components from model***

The model should contain data rather than components. Storing components in the model defeats the idea of renderers and editors. For more details see [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Swing Models and Renderers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPSwingModels.fm.html). Check out the following example the mimics button group behavior in the model:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ButtonGroupMockupTest {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                { "Group 1", Boolean.FALSE }, { "Group 2", Boolean.FALSE },
                { "Group 3", Boolean.FALSE } },
                new Object[] { "Name", "State" }) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
                if (col == 1)
                    return Boolean.class;
                return super.getColumnClass(col);
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                super.setValueAt(value, row, col);
                if (col == 1 && value.equals(Boolean.TRUE))
                    deselectValues(row, col);
            }

            private void deselectValues(int selectedRow, int col) {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                    if (getValueAt(row, col).equals(Boolean.TRUE)
                            && row != selectedRow) {
                        setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, row, col);
                        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new BooleanRadionRenderer());
        table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class, new BooleanRadioEditor());

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    static class BooleanRadionRenderer implements TableCellRenderer, UIResource {
        JRadioButton radioButton;
        Border emptyBorder;

        public BooleanRadionRenderer() {
            radioButton = new JRadioButton();
            radioButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JRadioButton.CENTER);
            radioButton.setBorderPainted(true);
            emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            if (isSelected) {
                radioButton.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
                radioButton.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                radioButton.setBackground(table.getBackground());
                radioButton.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
            if (hasFocus)
                radioButton.setBorder(UIManager
                        .getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            else
                radioButton.setBorder(emptyBorder);

            radioButton.setSelected(((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
            return radioButton;
        }
    }

    static class BooleanRadioEditor extends AbstractCellEditor 
                                    implements TableCellEditor {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JRadioButton radioButton;

        public BooleanRadioEditor() {
            radioButton = new JRadioButton();
            radioButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JRadioButton.CENTER);
            radioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // prevent deselection to mimic button group
                    if (!radioButton.isSelected())
                        cancelCellEditing();
                    stopCellEditing();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int col) {
            radioButton.setSelected(((Boolean) value).booleanValue());
            return radioButton;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return Boolean.valueOf(radioButton.isSelected());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Oh god I am an idiot! I was using setEnabled instead of setSelected...

Working with java guis for a week and a half has fried my brain.

Comment: -1 for storing components in the model (the OP copying an old, incorrect example is no excuse to repeat it ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra agree! I amended the answer with an example of group like implementation in the model.

Comment: @Phox please checkout my last update that eliminates components from the model.

Comment: I plan to revisit the code and clean it up. So I'll try fix the radio buttons to use data rather than the components

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to repaint() your JTable ?

Is the checkbox always unchecked or is there some case in which it is not ?

Hovercraft Full Of Eels is right : could you post a bunch of your code ?

Comment: turns out i royally messed up and used setEnabled instead of setSelected. It was completely a goof on my part.

Comment: :p no problem, we all do this sometimes !

Comment: I was wrong too, the repaint() solution worked for a project of mine where i was generating "picture" buttons, but (what an idiot) you are in a totally different case !

Comment: with a well-behaved (read: correctly notifying) model a repaint is _never_ needed. If that seems to resolve update problems, something is wrong elsewhere